# celery с версией 3.1.25 не работает

Tags: python, redis, celery

Я ещё новичок в celery поэтому решил пробовать максимально простой вариант. А именно сортировка чисел. Но и тут у меня не работает celery. Ранее уже гуглил и нашёл ответ что нужна версия 3.1.25! Так вот после этого деинсталлировал celery(и вообще всё что с ней связано) и заново её установил с версией 3.1.25. Но опять ничего не работает!
Вот содержимое файла tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery


app = Celery(
    "tasks",
    backend="redis://localhost:6379/1",
    broker="redis://localhost:6379/2"
)


@app.task()
def celery_sort(iterable):
    return sorted(iterable)
```

а это app.py

```
from tasks import celery_sort


result = celery_sort.delay([10, 22, 132, 100, 12312])
print(result.ready())
res = result.get()
```

и файл docker-compose.yml для redis

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

и вот pip freeze

```
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.23
celery==3.1.25
kombu==3.0.37
pytz==2021.1
redis==3.5.3
```

Попробовал запускать в Ubuntu но и там точно такая же ошибка!
Вот текст ошибки

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python38\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 311, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 785, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 713, in execute
    return cls(
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", line 179, in run_from_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 274, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", line 194, in run
    pool_cls = (concurrency.get_implementation(pool_cls) or
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\__init__.py", line 29, in get_implementation
    return symbol_by_name(cls, ALIASES)
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\__init__.py", line 96, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\prefork.py", line 20, in <module>
    from celery.concurrency.base import BasePool
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\concurrency\base.py", line 21, in <module>
    from celery.utils import timer2
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\timer2.py", line 19
    from kombu.async.timer import Entry, Timer as Schedule, to_timestamp, logger
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

а вот команда для запуска

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
```

Comment: ах да извините забыл) прикрепил в самый низ)

Comment: Это ошибка говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь запускать слишком старый celery на слишком новом питоне (async стало ключевым словом с версии питона 3.5). Поставьте или новый celery, или старый питон

Comment: Вы написали что-то очень странное, новый celery замечтательно работает с новыми питонами

Comment: ой всмысле не питон а windows) Когда гуглил нашел ответ что celery не поддерживает windows с версии 4 и я нашел ответ что надо было установить celery 3.1.25 https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3551   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511905/cannot-start-celery-worker-kombu-asynchronous-timer

Comment: Раз вы используете докер, то и celery запускайте тоже в докере, в нём не windows

Comment: ок спасибо попробую